# Steamworks.NET get current branch

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, steam, steamworks-api

My game on steam has two branches (betas) - default and beta_test. I want to show ingame bug report form, only when someone is playing with beta_test branch chosen. Is it possible to determine from the code, which branch is currently set? Or any other way, other than just uploading different builds for each branch.

Comment: You could pass in constants on the beta version while compiling. This is set within the Unity Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if anybody came here looking for answer, SteamApps.GetCurrentBetaName was what I was looking for. I dont know how I could miss this.